# when macro control flow in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Code for `when` macro taken from [subr.el](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/subr.el)

```
(defmacro when (cond &rest body)
  (declare (indent 1) (debug t))
  (list 'if cond (cons 'progn body)))
```

here, the last form is complex like,

```
(list 'if cond (cons 'progn body))
```

when the list is constructed, has it already done the evaluation of `cond` and `body` forms? 
Why has the programmer used `list` in one place & `cons` in another place? doesn't both of them take multiple forms & churn out a list?

```
(list 'if cond (.......))
(cons 'progn body)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros operate on *code*. Thus when the macro `when` is expanded (i.e., the macroexpansion function is called), symbols `cond` and `body` are bound to the expressions (symbols or lists) which you wrote.

E.g., if you write

```
(when (plusp 1)
  (print 'yes)
  (+ 1 2 3))
```

the macroexpansion is called with arguments bound to:

```
cond = (plusp 1)
body = ((print 'yes) (+ 1 2 3))
```

thus the expression

```
(list 'if cond (cons 'progn body))
```

evauates to

```
(let ((cond '(plusp 1))
      (body '((print 'yes) (+ 1 2 3))))
  (list 'if cond (cons 'progn body)))
==> (if (plusp 1) (progn (print (quote yes)) (+ 1 2 3)))
```

which is exactly what you want.

Finally, [`list` and `cons`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html) are quite different, please read their docs (<kbd>C-h f list RET</kbd>&c) and [the fine manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Lisp-Lists.html).

Answer (score 3):

Difference between `list` and `cons`:

```
(list 'progn '((foo) (bar)))
;;=> (progn ((foo) (bar)))

(cons 'progn '((foo) (bar)))
;;=> (progn (foo) (bar))
```